# Optimal way to modify a list in a function without copy in R

Tags: r, environment

I am writing a package where I need to modify a big list through a series of functions.
What are the possible ways to achieve this?

I am attaching my implementation but not sure if this is the optimum.

```r
##' @export
test <- function(param = TRUE){
  x <- list("a"= data.frame(a1 = c(1,2), a2 = c(1,1)),
            "b"= data.frame(b1 = c(2,3), b2 = c(1,2)))
  message(paste("in test() function, references to x[[1]]:", inspect(x)[["children"]][[1]][["address"]]))
  message(paste("in test() function, references to x[[2]]:", inspect(x)[["children"]][[2]][["address"]]))
  for(name in names(x)) updateList(x, name)
  message(paste("in test() function, post update references to x[[1]]:", inspect(x)[["children"]][[1]][["address"]]))
  message(paste("in test() function, post update references to x[[2]]:", inspect(x)[["children"]][[2]][["address"]]))
  x
}

updateList <- function(x, name){
  message(paste("updateList() references to x[[1]]:", inspect(x)[["children"]][[1]][["address"]]))
  message(paste("updateList() references to x[[2]]:", inspect(x)[["children"]][[2]][["address"]]))
  newdf <- rbind(x[[name]], c(4,4))
  assign("temp", newdf, envir = parent.frame(n = 1))
  with(parent.frame(n = 1), x[[name]] <- temp)
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

In the `Console`, when I run `test()`

```r
> library(pryr)
> test()
in test() function, references to x[[1]]: 0x55d66ce9dd98
in test() function, references to x[[2]]: 0x55d670954508
updateList() references to x[[1]]: 0x55d66ce9dd98
updateList() references to x[[2]]: 0x55d670954508
updateList() references to x[[1]]: 0x55d66fca1688
updateList() references to x[[2]]: 0x55d670954508
in test() function, post update references to x[[1]]: 0x55d66fca1688
in test() function, post update references to x[[2]]: 0x55d66ffb8208
$a
  a1 a2
1  1  1
2  2  1
3  4  4

$b
  b1 b2
1  2  1
2  3  2
3  4  4
```

Is there a way to make sure that R is not copying? How to know if it has created copies in-between?

As suggested by @len-greski, we can see the address of each element, We can see that at each iteration only one data-frame is copied and rests aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `environment` is a good option.

```
k <- lapply(1:100000, identity)
names(k) <- as.character(1:length(k))
f <- function(x, i){x[[i]] <- x[[i]]*2; x}
system.time(for(i in 1:length(k)) f(k, as.character(i)))
```

This takes almost 2.5 sec on my machine.

```
e2 <- list2env(k, hash = FALSE)
system.time(for(i in 1:length(k)) f(e2, as.character(i)))
```

With `environment` it takes 0.3 seconds. 10 times faster!! With `hash = TRUE`, it is 100 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine whether R is copying objects with `pryr::address()` and `pryr::refs()`. Here we'll add `message()` functions to check the address of `x` in `test()` and `updateList()` to show that the objects are being copied.

```
library(pryr)
test <- function(param = TRUE){
     x <- list("a"= data.frame(a1 = c(1,2), a2 = c(1,1)),
               "b"= data.frame(b1 = c(2,3), b2 = c(1,2)))
     message(paste("in test() function, references to x:",c(address(x)," ",refs(x))))
     for(name in names(x)) updateList(x, name)
     message(paste("in test() function, post update references to x:",c(address(x)," ",refs(x))))
     x
}

updateList <- function(x, name){
     message(paste("updateList() references to x:",c(address(x)," ",refs(x))))
     newdf <- rbind(x[[name]], c(4,4))
     assign("temp", newdf, envir = parent.frame(n = 1))
     with(parent.frame(n = 1), x[[name]] <- temp)
     invisible(NULL)
}
```

...and the output.

```
> test()
in test() function, address of x: 0x7fbbcfaf02c8 references: 1
updateList() address of x: 0x7fbbcf696730 references: 0
updateList() address of x: 0x7fbbcf6846c0 references: 0
in test() function, post update address of x: 0x7fbbcfa3d6c8 references: 1
$a
  a1 a2
1  1  1
2  2  1
3  4  4

$b
  b1 b2
1  2  1
2  3  2
3  4  4

>
```

From the changes in the address of `x` between pre-update and post-update we can see that it is being copied.

Comment: Thanks. I think x is getting copied. If I am correct, in memory, x is just a vector of two elements that stores the addresses of data.frame objects. In this case, only the vector containing the addresses will change, at the same time only one data-frame would be created in the parent-frame and other list-associated data-frames will not get copied. 

However, I am not sure. address(x) function only provide the addresses, not the values. If we could get values at those locations then I can confirm. or something like address of (x[["a"]]).

Comment: I figured it `inspect(x)[["children"]][[1]][["address"]]` and `inspect(x)[["children"]][[2]][["address"]]` can be used to trace the address of data-frames

Comment: @ShubhamGupta - you're welcome. Please upvote if you found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In R, modifying the list will result in copying of the entire list.

You may want to consider using an `R6` object, which are mutable. Here are a couple of resources:

- https://r6.r-lib.org/
- https://adv-r.hadley.nz/r6.html

Comment: This is not true. I have added some code that can display the address of each element. In this implementation, only one element is copied.

Comment: Yeah, I read it more closely and I see that you are modifying the environment, not a specific list. The environment is mutable. I guess "a list" is not mutable, but "the list" as defined here is.

Comment: Yes. There is `list2env` function that can do it in a much better way. But I don't know how to use that properly in this example.

Comment: I still believe that it may be worth your while to look into `R6`. Not sure what that would do to your workflow, but might be useful. Good luck!